# Friendly Urls in DotNetNuke - Troubleshooting

Tags: url, module, dotnetnuke, friendly-url, seo

In DNN, I'm using Host Settings -> Friendly Url Settings to try and make a page url SEO-friendly.  But I keep getting an error and I don't know why.

Current URL format:

```
http://localhost/dnn/Admin/MyPage.aspx?title=news-article-name-written-here
```

Desired URL format:

```
http://localhost/dnn/Admin/MyPage/news-article-name-written-here
```

"Friendly Url Settings" rule:

```
MATCH:  .*/MyPage/(.*) REPLACE WITH:  ~/Admin/MyPage.aspx?title=$1
```

Error:

> Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE/DNN"
>
> Internet Information Services 7.5 Error Summary HTTP Error 404.0 - Not
>   Found
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

As a side note, I'm not interested in buying any specialized DNN modules to do this (or using the free iFinity one).  Any ideas at all what I might be doing wrong?  Or, if this is impossible for some reason, could anybody please explain why?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, solved it - as it turns out, you can't drop file extensions with the default DNN Url Rewriter.  So here's what I did instead:

1. Installed the urlrewrite extension on my IIS
   (http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)
2. Added the following code snippet to the `<system.webServer>` tag of the dnn site's web.config:

`<rewrite><rules><rule name="UrlRewriteService" stopProcessing="true"><match url="^.*/MyPage/(.*)$"/><action type="Rewrite" url="Admin/MyPage.aspx?title={R:1}" /></rule></rules></rewrite>`

Hope that helps somebody else!