# URL rewriting breaks with question mark

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke

I want to rewrite url (DotNetNuke Friendly URLs) like so:

From: `/search.aspx?query=test` To: `~/SearchResults?search=test`

I have tried various combinations but it looks like it doesnt take into account the part of the url after the question mark

```
  <RewriterRule>
      <LookFor>.*/search.aspx?query=(.+)</LookFor>
      <SendTo>~/SearchResults?Search=$1</SendTo>
  </RewriterRule>
```

But it doesnt work..

I have tried:

```
  <RewriterRule>
      <LookFor>.*/search.aspx\?query=(.+)</LookFor>
      <SendTo>~/SearchResults?Search=$1</SendTo>
  </RewriterRule>
```

but this also doesnt work for the url `/search.aspx?query=test` . I get a 404 for search.aspx

This is the related part in DotNetNuke's web.config:

```
<friendlyUrl defaultProvider="DNNFriendlyUrl">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DNNFriendlyUrl"
         type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" 
         includePageName="true" 
         regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" 
         urlFormat="humanfriendly" />
  </providers>
</friendlyUrl>
```

Is there something that is causing it to skip `?`

This is the source code of the friendly url rewriter if that helps.. I am not that great with regex so I could use some help.

https://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/Content/Community/HttpModules/UrlRewrite/UrlRewriteModule.cs

Comment: Maybe this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083316/friendly-urls-in-dotnetnuke-troubleshooting.

Comment: that adds another url rewriter to the mix.. i am hoping to solve this without enabling IIS url rewriter. as the one with DNN can be modified by the admin..

Comment: I am not good with regex.. do you think it is skipping due to regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]"  in the web.config? I tried added '?' and '\?' but then I get a 500 error on the whole site

Answer (score 5):

```
.*/search.aspx\?query=(.+)
```

You have to escape the ? with a \ since it's a regex keyword

Comment: Not working for me :(    '<RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>.*/search.aspx\?query=(.+)</LookFor>
    <SendTo>~/SearchResults?Search=$2</SendTo>
   </RewriterRule>'

Comment: @DanielGimenez are you sure? Did you test it with a DNN site?

Comment: @VaibhavGarg: No, I tested it with my own website, and the IIS url rewrite module.

Answer (score 0):

The question marks needs to be escaped with a "\?"

```
    <RewriterRule>
      <LookFor>.*/search.aspx\?query=(.+)$</LookFor>
      <SendTo>~/SearchResults?Search=$1</SendTo>
    </RewriterRule>
```